# Can any one explain why we need if (prime[2]!=1) to assign the values to the array while all the values of the array are initially set to be zero?

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3gpo.png)

I have this code as an assignment where I should store values for each number from 0 to 100. Prime numbers are assigned the value 1 while non-prime are assigned the value 0. The code without the If statement and simply a return statement at the end makes more sense especially that the If condition is always true since all values of the array are initiated with zero, however, without the If, the code doesn't function properly. It usually returns 0 for all numbers. So the If condition here is crucial but can anybody explain why and what does it do here to make the code work?

Comment: Don't post pictures of code here.

Comment: To answer your question, the `if` statement is there to see if the array has been populated.  If it hasn't, the code under the `if` populates it.  The function will not work without a properly populated array.  Note that the array is declared `static`, which means that the array will only be populated once.  Also, note that this code appears to have a bug; the `if` side of that conditional statement doesn't return anything.

Comment: `return` statement won't be executed in the first execution of this function. It may cause some troubles.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for an explanation of how the code works.